# Collections.shuffle(list) doesn't shuffle my list

Tags: java, android, collections, shuffle

i have a problem on my Quiz application. I have to suffle my list of question (taken from Firebase database) but my code seems to be wrong.

File Start.java:

```
private void loadQuestion(String categoryId) {

        //First, clear list if have old question
        if(Common.questionList.size() > 0)
            Common.questionList.clear();

        questions.orderByChild("CategoryId").equalTo(categoryId)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            Question ques = postSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                            Common.questionList.add(ques);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
        //Random list
        Collections.shuffle(Common.questionList);
    }
```

and file Common.java:

```
public class Common {
    public static String categoryId;
    public  static User currentUser;
    public static List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is being added via a callback `addValueEventListener`

At the beginning of your function, you clear your list:

```
        Common.questionList.clear();
```

So `Collections.suffle` does shuffle on your empty list only

What you want is to place that shuffle function in your callback:

```
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Question ques = postSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                        Common.questionList.add(ques);
                    }
                    // Shuffle it
                    Collections.shuffle(Common.questionList);

                }
```